# Using Parameter in the SELECT statement in SQL C#

Tags: c#, sql-server, t-sql

I have the below T-SQL query working correctly in SSMS.

```
DECLARE @StartDTTM DATE = '2020-04-25'
DECLARE @EndDTTM DATE = '2020-05-02'

CREATE TABLE #Temp
(
    D_Date DATE,
)

WHILE @StartDTTM <= @EndDTTM
BEGIN
    INSERT INTO #Temp
        SELECT @StartDTTM AS D_DATE

    SET @StartDTTM = DATEADD(DAY, 1, @StartDTTM)
END

SELECT * FROM #Temp
DROP TABLE #Temp
```

But when called from C# & `System.Data.SqlClient`, all the columns have startdate hardcoded and the iteration date is not picking up.

```
using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(QueryText))
{
    cmd.Connection = conn;
    cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;

    SqlParameter param;
    param = new SqlParameter("@StartDTTM", '2020-04-25');
    cmd.Parameters.Add(param);
    param = new SqlParameter("@EndDTTM", '2020-05-02');
    cmd.Parameters.Add(param);

    using (SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter())
    {
        da.SelectCommand = cmd;
        da.Fill(ds);
    };
};
```

Edit 1: I have additional logic in the query. I am trying to get the values in a table for iteration date falling between two date columns, basically snapshot of the values for the iteration date. Hope it helps

Edit 2: When passed through SQL Command the `@StartDTTM` is changed to the value and then the query is passed to SQL. Hence the rows are all start date. Is there a work around?

Comment: Use a more precise form to define a parameter _new SqlParameter("@Start", SqlDbType.Date); param.Value = new DateTime(2020,4,25);_

Comment: what do you mean " all the columns have startdate hardcoded " - there's only one column here; what are you seeing? also: why go to the database for this? you can loop on dates just fine in C#... (also: why DataTable? and note: it is dangerous to create a `#Temp` table this way, since it will live longer than the query; you might want to use a `@Temp` table variable instead)

Comment: Can you please share QueryText that you are passing here?

Comment: Query Text is same as the SQL mentioned

Comment: @MarcGravell: I have edited the post with additional info, I am droping the temp table at the end of the query, is it still a performance constriant?

Comment: If query text is exactly as you have typed it in the question then I doubt that it is working correctly. Every command should be separated by a semicolon if you want to pass that text from C# code.

Comment: I think as @Steve has correctly mentioned, The reason for this issue is that you are not mentioning DataType of SqlParameter. I suggest you to do what Steve has mentioned and share.